# Renamed app causing errors in emulator

Tags: android, time, countdowntimer

I have already run the an app in my emulator, now I've renamed it again and run to make changes to my app, but I'm getting following errors in my emulator:

```
[2012-02-23 11:12:55 - CountDownTime] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2012-02-23 11:12:55 - CountDownTime] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2012-02-23 11:12:55 - CountDownTime] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.examples' in a shell.
[2012-02-23 11:12:55 - CountDownTime] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At First Uninstall the application from your emulator.and run the application after uninstalling.

To Uninstall the application follow the procedure.

In Your Emulator

```
      goto settings->Applications->Manage Application->Select Ur Project Name->and Click Uninstall Button.
```

[image]

Comment: in emulator i didnt found this settings option

Comment: See at Ur home Screen settings icon will be there.by defaultly for every emulator it will be there like our phone.

Comment: For Ur Reference i added the image also.check it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Deepu you have to uninstall you application from emulator and again run and then check.

I think you problem will be solved.

Thanks.